# Get all fields inlcuding "ACF" (Advanced Custom Fields) columns in wp_query

Tags: wp-query, loop, advanced-custom-fields

When retrieving posts with wp_query how do I make the loop contain the acf fields?

```
    $args = array( 'post_type' => $postTypes, 
                   'posts_per_page' => $numPosts, 
                   'offset' => $offset,
                   'meta_query' => $filterArgs );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

$postTypes is an array I have filled in advance containing "post", "page" etc. whatever I need.

The loop will contain only the "standard" WP columns like post_content and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop doesn't really contain anything.

It does include methods in order to easily output your data such as `the_title()`, this is done when calling `the_post()`

Then, within the loop you'll be able to use get_the_ID() and get_post_meta() to get your custom fields (including ACF ones).

So if you have retrieved your desired posts from that query then you'll be able to do this:

```
<?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>   
   <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>  
   <?php the_content(); ?>
   <p>My Custom Field: <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'my-custom-field', true); ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Works like a charme, Steven. Thanks! I combine $post and $fields in a new array and off I go ;-)